# How to integrate Enthought Canopy with SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, scikit-learn, enthought, canopy

I am new to Python and using Enthought Canopy Express for learning purpose. 
As part of that I am looking for an option to connect Canopy Express with SQL Server. Couldn't find any materials.
Please share methods for database connection for data collection?

Answer (score 0):

[PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) defines a standard interface for database programming in Python.  There are a number of Python packages implementing that interface that can help you connect with SQL Server.  You might try looking at `pyodbc`.  There are some others listed [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server)

If you just want to get some experience using SQL statements in Python, you might want to start with the `sqlite3` package.